# How to diagnose wp-env environment problem

Tags: theme-development, javascript, block-editor

### Short version

```
% node -v
v14.16.0
% npm -v
7.6.1
% wp-env --version
3.0.2
% npx @wordpress/create-block foo
...
Done: block "Foo" bootstrapped in the "foo" folder.
% cd foo
% wp-env start
✖ Error while running docker-compose command.
Creating e6bc9159b910bda3d9b0dae2e230eabd_cli_run ... done
mysqlcheck: Got error: 1130: Host '172.18.0.5' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server when trying to connect
```

I'm assuming I've messed up something in my node or wp-env environment, but am not sure where or for what to look.

---

### Long Version

I'm new to all this (new dev environment, node, etc...), but was successfully developing a new block. Then I decided, well, this all seems to make sense, so next time I develop a theme, I'm going to try and do it with OOP and ESNext. After digging around a bit, I decided to start with this [WordPress theme boilerplate](https://github.com/hasnaindev/wordpress-theme-boilerplate).

I had to do some fiddling around to get it to work, and, honestly, I can't remember all the steps I took, but, it's still working. I can `wp-env start` and `run start`, from inside its directory, and it's just fine:

```
% wp-env start
WordPress development site started at http://localhost:8888/
WordPress test site started at http://localhost:8889/
MySQL is listening on port 55002

 ✔ Done! (in 10s 270ms)
% npm start

> wp-theme-cwra-2021@0.99.1 start
> npm run dev
...
Entrypoint main = runtime.js main.js
[0] [./src/scripts/index.js] 51 bytes {main} [built]
[0] [./src/scripts/lib/lazy-load.js] 233 bytes {main} [built]
[0]     + 1 hidden module
[0] [Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:8888
[0] [Browsersync] Access URLs:
[0]  ------------------------------------
[0]        Local: http://localhost:3000
[0]     External: http://192.168.1.6:3000
[0]  ------------------------------------
[0]           UI: http://localhost:3001
[0]  UI External: http://localhost:3001
[0]  ------------------------------------
[0] [Browsersync] Watching files...
```

So ... somehow in fiddling around to get this working, I broke the default wp-env stuff, but I have no idea how, nor how to go about finding what broke. Any suggestions on how to track this down?

Thanks!

(`package.json` dependencies and `webpack.config.js` from the working theme included below for completeness)

```
// package.json
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.13",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.21.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "stylelint": "^13.11.0",
    "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines": "^7.1.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lozad": "^1.16.0"
  }
```

and

```
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = ({ mode }) => {
  const isProduction = mode === 'production';

  const entry = './src/scripts/index.js';

  const output = {
    path: path.resolve('assets', 'scripts'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: 'wp-content'
      .concat(
        path
          .join(__dirname, 'assets', 'scripts', '/')
          .split('wp-content')
          .pop()
      ),
  };

  const devtool = isProduction
    ? 'source-map'
    : 'inline-source-map';

  const module = {
    rules: [
      { test: /.js$/, exclude: /(node_modules)/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
    ],
  };

  const plugins = [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: 'localhost',
      proxy: 'localhost:8888',
      port: 3000,
      injectChanges: true,
      notify: true,
      files: [
        {
          match: ['**/*.php', 'assets/scripts/*.js', 'assets/styles/*.css'],
          fn(event, file) {
            event === 'change'
            && file.split('.').pop() === 'css'
              ? this.reload('*.css')
              : this.reload();
          },
        },
      ],
    }, {
      reload: false,
    }),
  ];

  const optimization = {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },
    },
  };

  return {
    entry,
    output,
    devtool,
    module,
    plugins,
    optimization,
    mode,
  };
};
```

Comment: Same problem here too   .............  :(

Comment: I haven't found "the answer", because this isn't really an answer. However, I ended up removing NVM, NPM, .wpenv, AND Docker and reinstalling and it fixed itself. I suspect a corrupted cached image somewhere, but removing either Docker or the other three didn't work; had to do everything at the same time.